# Stop foreach loop when curl return 200

Tags: php, api, curl, proxmox

I try to communicate with my Proxmox cluster which contain 3 servers, from API. Goal is to connect to at least 1 of these servers in case of failure then execute other code (not visible here).

With the below code, I connect to these servers 1 by 1 using "foreach" and I want this loop stop when one server return "200" from Curl (so I can continue with this online server). For the test, I stopped the first server and let online the others 2 but the "foreach" loop keep connect the third server.

Any idea ? Thank you and sorry for my english.

```
<?php

$datas = array(
    array(
        "apiurl" => "192.168.1.34:8006",
        "node" => "pve1",
        "user" => "root",
        "userpass" => "pass",
    ),
    array(
        "apiurl" => "192.168.1.35:8006",
        "node" => "pve2",
        "user" => "root",
        "userpass" => "pass",
    ),
    array(
        "apiurl" => "192.168.1.36:8006",
        "node" => "pve3",
        "user" => "root",
        "userpass" => "pass",
    )
);

do {
    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$data['apiurl'].'/api2/json/access/ticket');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$data['user'].'@pam&password='.$data['userpass']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Server ' .$data['node']. ' is not reachable (error : ' .curl_error($ch). ')<br>';
        }
        else {
            $myArray = json_decode($result, true);
            $cookie = $myArray['data']['ticket'];
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            echo "Server " .$data['node']. " is reachable (code is : " .$info['http_code']. ")<br>";
        }
    curl_close($ch);
    }
} while ($info['http_code'] !== 200);
?>
```

Comment: What `foreach` loop? You have a `while` loop here. `foreach` only traverses the array. This loop is obviously infinite.

Comment: I thought the "do while" would stop the "foreach" loop with "while ($info['http_code'] !== 200);". But i'm wrong and I don't see how to solve my problem.

Comment: It won't. The `foreach` loop traverses the entire array **first** before we even get to the `while` loop. And since the `while` condition will **always** be `false` by the time we get to through the `foreach` loop the `while` loop will continue forever.

Comment: To correct my previous comment, I mean to say that the `while` condition will **always** be `true`, obviously, not `false`, since `false` would cause it to stop.

Comment: Ok, I see... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break out of an outer loop by giving an argument to `break`. `break 2` means to break out of the second containing loop.

```
while (true) {
    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$data['apiurl'].'/api2/json/access/ticket');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$data['user'].'@pam&password='.$data['userpass']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Server ' .$data['node']. ' is not reachable (error : ' .curl_error($ch). ')<br>';
        }
        else {
            $myArray = json_decode($result, true);
            $cookie = $myArray['data']['ticket'];
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            echo "Server " .$data['node']. " is reachable (code is : " .$info['http_code']. ")<br>";
            if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `break 2`, BTW, `break` alone is fine. Especially if you expect any logic inside of the `while` loop to happen regardless of success or failure. It's not wrong in this case since there is none, but it's not necessary either.

Comment: `break` will just break out of the `foreach` loop, but the `while` loop will continue.

Comment: No, the while loop will stop because the condition will become `false` since we now have a `$info['http_code'] == 200`.

Comment: True, but why check the same condition twice?

Comment: Read the rest of my previous comment. Or see my answer for a lengthier explanation.

Comment: I deleted the while loop and modified the break (deleted "2"). It works fine.

Comment: If you delete the `while` loop then you'll stop when all the servers fail, you won't go back to the beginning.

Comment: Ok I see. But if all the servers fails, my script is useless ;-).

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is an infinite loop, because as you stated you already know the last 2 servers in the array won't respond successfully, yet your `foreach` loop will try all 3 regardless of success or failure. So by the time you get to the 3rd iteration of the `foreach` loop you get a failed response and **then** you reach the end of the `while` loop which determines the condition is still `true` and continues. To prevent this simply break from the `foreach` loop once success is determined. Because only **then** will the condition of the `while` loop become `false`. You can also break out of both loops if you'd like (using `break 2`). Either one is correct. The only difference is if you wanted any remaining logic inside the outter (`while`) loop to happen regardless of success or failure.

```
foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$data['apiurl'].'/api2/json/access/ticket');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$data['user'].'@pam&password='.$data['userpass']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Server ' .$data['node']. ' is not reachable (error : ' .curl_error($ch). ')<br>';
        }
        else {
            $myArray = json_decode($result, true);
            $cookie = $myArray['data']['ticket'];
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            echo "Server " .$data['node']. " is reachable (code is : " .$info['http_code']. ")<br>";
            if (!empty($info['http_code']) && $info['http_code'] == 200) {
                break; // break out of either or both loops since we got a valid response
            }
        }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```